# Angular dependecy injection lookup and module injector hierarchy

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

As I understood each Angular module has its own injector.

However during compilation all the modules are [merged](https://indepth.dev/posts/1056/avoiding-common-confusions-with-modules-in-angular#modules-hierarchy) in one single.

> The biggest confusion regarding imported modules is that developers
> think they make a hierarchy. And it’s probably reasonable to assume
> that a module that imports other modules becomes the parent module for
> its imports. However, that’s not what happens. All modules are merged
> during compilation phase. And thus **there’s no hierarchical
> relationship between the module that is imported and the module that
> imports**.

Therefore it is not clear how injectors from all merged modules form a module injector hierarchy if there is no any hierachal relationships between modules? - It is the same if to declare all servicies in one root module - what are hierarchal relationships will be in that case?

**UPDATE 1:**
From the [link](https://indepth.dev/posts/1261/what-you-always-wanted-to-know-about-angular-dependency-injection-tree) provided by Daniel Perales follows:

1. That the module injector tree (hierarchy) was introduced along side with component injection tree for [fixing](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/13686bb) the [bug](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13722) with lazy loaded modules.
2. Angular indeed merges all modules service providers in a single AppModule factory, which "returns the module definition with all merged providers."

So, it looks like that top level element in the module injector hierarchy is the  AppModule factory and the following elements are injector defenitions from lazy loaded modules.

Any thoughts about it?

Comment: "As I understood each Angular module has its own injector." - This might not be true. I cannot find this info in official Angular docs but there is an article - https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/how-dependency-injection-resolution-works-in-angular/#injector
Also I have made stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ag6rzb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fgrand-child%2Fgrand-child.module.ts 
Where you can compare injectors of 3 modules (ex. app === child) and it's everywhere same instance.

Answer (score 0):

Angular DI is a very complex topic and the way it is done has evolved across versions. In modern Angular it is a safe bet to provide services with the syntax "provided in root" to allow tree-shaking and avoid pitfalls, and only in some particular cases do it manually in providers array of modules or components.

Here are two good articles on the topic:

https://indepth.dev/what-you-always-wanted-to-know-about-angular-dependency-injection-tree

https://indepth.dev/posts/1261/what-you-always-wanted-to-know-about-angular-dependency-injection-tree

Comment: Thanks for the link provided!, Lets look may be someone will comment on the update